# Razor has three different ways to set "class" attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is the code generated from "Add View" wizard in ASP .NET MVC5 project:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, there are three different ways the "class" attribute is set on an html control. Why this anomaly? Also, is one preferred over the other? Regards.

Comment: Using `new { @class = "text-danger" }` is typical for most helpers, but `EditorFor()` requires `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }`. Prior to MVC5, you could not add html attributes (except passing `additionalViewData` to a custom `EditorTemplate`. I believe the `.. new { htmlAttributes = new { ...}}` was required to avoid any potential conflict with the overload that accepted `additionalViewData`

Comment: @Peter can you see any difference in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st and the 3rd are the same. The 1st is a naming parameter. You can use this way for more clarity but it is not required.

But the 2nd example pass html attributes into another object which agregates it. And you cannot use this way for two previous. In the MVC sources this object is converted to the KeyValuePair:

```
if (additionalViewData != null)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary(additionalViewData))
    {
        viewData[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are all the same!

I prefer this one `htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }` because it shows the parameter name clearly.Otherwise, the other two options are all good.

Comment: They are **NOT** the same. `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" } })` would generate `<label for="City" htmlattributes="{ class = control-label col-md-2 }">Name</label>` (invalid html and no class name!)